# Datatables PDF Export Custom Sum Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, datatable

Using `Datatables v1.10` I would like to export my table, including a HTML element that is **outside** of the table, which includes the sum of a salary column - is this possible? This sum changes dynamically and the live result should be exported when the button is clicked.

I have created a table that successfully filters, displays the total, and exports a PDF with a custom message, but I'm not sure how I can add my `total` element to the PDF.

I'd like the PDF layout to be as follows;

1. PDF Title
2. Total Salary Value
3. Table Contents

I've created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1kesnup6/1/) and code is below.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        messageTop: 'PDF created by PDFMake with Buttons for DataTables.'
      }],
      "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api(),
          data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function(i) {
          return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ?
            i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
          .column(4)
          .data()
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
          .column(4, {
            page: 'current'
          })
          .data()
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
          '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
        );
        $('#total').text('£' + Number(pageTotal).toFixed(2));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<p>Total Salary: <span id="total"></span></p>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod</td>
      <td>Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona</td>
      <td>Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen</td>
      <td>Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya</td>
      <td>Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena</td>
      <td>Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn</td>
      <td>Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde</td>
      <td>Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley</td>
      <td>Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana</td>
      <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria</td>
      <td>Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai</td>
      <td>Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette</td>
      <td>Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri</td>
      <td>Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar</td>
      <td>Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris</td>
      <td>Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica</td>
      <td>Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden</td>
      <td>Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou</td>
      <td>Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle</td>
      <td>House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki</td>
      <td>Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott</td>
      <td>Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena</td>
      <td>Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard</td>
      <td>Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope</td>
      <td>Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian</td>
      <td>Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy</td>
      <td>Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia</td>
      <td>Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno</td>
      <td>Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura</td>
      <td>Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor</td>
      <td>Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn</td>
      <td>Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge</td>
      <td>Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita</td>
      <td>Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara</td>
      <td>Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas</td>
      <td>Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad</td>
      <td>Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [enable footer](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/footer.html) to export it.

```
buttons: [{
   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   messageTop: function(){
      return "Total Salary: " + $("#total").text();
    },
   footer: true
}],
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [{
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        messageTop: function(){
          return "Total Salary: " + $("#total").text();
        },
        footer: true
      }],
      "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api(),
          data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function(i) {
          return typeof i === 'string' ?
            i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ?
            i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
          .column(4)
          .data()
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
          .column(4, {
            page: 'current'
          })
          .data()
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
          }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
          '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
        );
        $('#total').text('£' + Number(pageTotal).toFixed(2));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<p>Total Salary: <span id="total"></span></p>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod</td>
      <td>Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona</td>
      <td>Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen</td>
      <td>Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya</td>
      <td>Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena</td>
      <td>Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn</td>
      <td>Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde</td>
      <td>Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley</td>
      <td>Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana</td>
      <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria</td>
      <td>Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai</td>
      <td>Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette</td>
      <td>Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri</td>
      <td>Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar</td>
      <td>Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris</td>
      <td>Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica</td>
      <td>Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden</td>
      <td>Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou</td>
      <td>Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle</td>
      <td>House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki</td>
      <td>Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott</td>
      <td>Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin</td>
      <td>Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena</td>
      <td>Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard</td>
      <td>Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope</td>
      <td>Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian</td>
      <td>Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy</td>
      <td>Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia</td>
      <td>Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno</td>
      <td>Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura</td>
      <td>Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor</td>
      <td>Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn</td>
      <td>Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge</td>
      <td>Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita</td>
      <td>Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer</td>
      <td>Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara</td>
      <td>Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
      <td>Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael</td>
      <td>Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas</td>
      <td>Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad</td>
      <td>Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna</td>
      <td>Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I have updated my answer, check it once.

Comment: Perfect - thanks! You may want to update your answer to include the function you added?